Raising an error in ANTLR Listener Golang Runtime
I'm using an Listener to walk the parse tree generated by the Go ANTLR runtime. Here's one of the methods of my Listener:
func (l *Listener) ExitProcedureBody(ctx *gen.ProcedureBodyContext) {
    l.push(&ast.ProcedureBody{
    StatementBlock: l.pop().(*ast.StatementBlock),
})}

I would like to be able to do some additional checking in my Listener methods and if an error condition is encountered raise an error. The error should abort the parse/walk.
How is the proper way to do this?
It would be nice if the generated Listener methods could return an error. But that is not how they were designed.
